# play a .mp4 or .mov video from either an Internet URL or a local file in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I play a **.mp4** or **.mov** video from either an `Internet URL` or a `local file` in iOS?

And how I can add several of videos in the collection view controller?

Answer (score 5):

Try this (MPMoviePlayerController):

```
NSArray *paths =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pathVideo = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyVideo.mp4"];
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathVideo];
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
[self.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
[self.moviePlayer setContentURL:movieURL.absoluteURL];
[self.moviePlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];
[self.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlModeDefault];
[self.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO];

[self.moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeNone];
self.moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, 240, 350);
[self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
[self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.moviePlayer play];
```

Comment: I think you mean `MPMovieControlStyleDefault` for the property `controlStyle` on the `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Answer (score 1):

Use MPMoviePlayerController

> A movie player (of type MPMoviePlayerController) manages the playback
>   of a movie from a file or a network stream. Playback occurs in a view
>   owned by the movie player and takes place either fullscreen or inline.
>   You can incorporate a movie player’s view into a view hierarchy owned
>   by your app, or use an MPMoviePlayerViewController object to manage
>   the presentation for you.

Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html