# live streaming using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-live-streaming

I'm working on live streaming of different channels. It work fine when using `MPMoviePlayerViewController`, but I want to add player as "subview". When I do this it does not work, a black screen come on player. Some time it work fine but after few second it show black again. I don't find any solution. I just want to add two button "Previous channel" and "Next channel" to change channel.Please help.

I am using below code:

```
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:nil];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];
[player setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming];
[player setFullscreen:YES];
[player.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];
player.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[pPlayerView addSubview: player.view];

[player play];
```

Comment: Try my post on this link: [mpmovieplayercontroller][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512106/play-a-mp4-or-mov-video-from-either-an-internet-url-or-a-local-file-in-ios/23512474#23512474

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried your code but same problem there.

Comment: Try player variable is iVar variable