# How to play video by tapping the UITableViewCell IOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, video-streaming

Hi in my application i have passing the video url from my server as `json` and I'm displaying the video title in my `UITableView`.I want to play the video by tapping the cell. I have tried some methods and they are not working.

My JSON fetching code for video :

```
-(void)details{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myurl"];


   
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

   NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

   NSLog(@"the str==%@",jsonString);

   NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];

   videoarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   NSArray *array=[results objectForKey:@"videos"];



  for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
    
     
    NSString *filed =[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"v_name"];

   //my video url stored in a nstring video
    NSString *video =[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"video"];
    
    NSLog(@"the url==%@",video);
    NSLog(@"the field==%@",filed);
    
    // i have ready nsobject to store the data and im adding to the nsmutablearray

    video1 *myimg =[[video1 alloc]initWithname:filed andvideo:video];
 
    [videoarray addObject:myimg];
    
    }

    [self.mytableview reloadData];  
  }
```

When I print the url its json its coming like this.

```
the url==http://jesusredeems.tv/media/videos/2014 Promise Message/Promise Message 2014-Part 2.mp4
```

After that in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method im giving like this.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   video1 * curnt = [videoarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


  MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL: [NSURL URLWithString:curnt.video]];
  [[player view] setFrame: [self.view bounds]];  // frame must match parent view
  [self.view addSubview: [player view]];
  [player play];
 }
```

I have used the above code to play the video while tapping the cell but after tapping the its showing the black screen like this.

[image]

I have already imported the `Media player` in my `UITableView` but its not working. Please tell me how to resolve this issue and where am I going wrong in the above code

Thanks.

Comment: video1 * curnt = [videoarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
what this is in your code?make it as nsstring.

Comment: @karthikeyan its nstring only

Comment: then do some url encoding it may causes.

Comment: where do you want to present movie player same or next view?

Comment: @karthikeyan please tell me how to do url encoding

Comment: @karthikeyan i want to display in next view

Comment: you need to set     [_moviePlayerTemp setShouldAutoplay:YES];
this.see my below answer its working fine.declare movieplayer  in global

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {




     //your array here

    NSString * currentVideo = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


   _moviePlayerTemp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[self urlencode:currentVideo]]];
    [[_moviePlayerTemp view] setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
// frame must match parent view
    [self.view addSubview: [_moviePlayerTemp view]];
    [_moviePlayerTemp setShouldAutoplay:YES];
    [_moviePlayerTemp prepareToPlay];
    [_moviePlayerTemp play];

}

-(NSString *)urlencode:(NSString *)str
{
    NSString *encodeString=(NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)str, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"", kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
    return encodeString;
}
```

and call like this..

```
NSString *string=@"http://jesusredeems.tv/media/videos/2014 Promise Message/Promise Message 2014-Part 2.mp4";
        NSString *temp=[self urlencode:string];
```

Comment: i used ur code but its giving error like NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[video1 length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa26e8f0'

Comment: which array you are getting a movie url?

Comment: please check the question there i have clearly mention where im passing the datas

Comment: ok...then pass your value next view.dont create movie player in didselect row.create it next view.

Comment: r utelling to create a anotherview controller and diplay the video

Comment: pleae tell where nstring *string

Comment: have you try this code?i created nsstring in didselect row delegate method for temporary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54701/discussion-between-user3614966-and-karthikeyan).

Answer (score 0):

Try to create `MPMoviePlayerController` like this post:  [play a .mp4 or .mov video from either an Internet URL or a local file in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512106/play-a-mp4-or-mov-video-from-either-an-internet-url-or-a-local-file-in-ios/23512474#23512474)

Besides that, create MPMoviePlayerController variable is an iVar variable NOT local variable in function like you do in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0):

Videos which are inside the app.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath {


   NSString *path  =[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"YOUR Video File Name" ofType:@"mp4"];
  _moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(playbackFinished:)
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:_moviePlayer];
[_moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit];
[_moviePlayer setFullscreen:FALSE];
self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
 _moviePlayer.view.frame = self.videoPlayerView.bounds;
  [_moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO];
 _videoPlayerView.hidden=NO;
  [self.videoPlayerView addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.videoPlayerView];

   [_moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
   [_moviePlayer play];

}
//After finishing playing.


-(void)finishedPlaying:(NSNotification *)sender
{
 MPMoviePlayerController *player  =[sender object];
 [player stop];
//    [player.view removeFromSuperview];
   self.videoPlayerView.hidden=YES;
   if([player isFullscreen])
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   _moviePlayer = nil;
  }
```